# PIVOT (without aggregation?) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to put together a select statement on some data like the below using TSQL:

Table1:

| Property | Detail | Record No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Surname | Smith | 1 |
| First Name | Anne | 1 |
| Title | Mrs | 1 |
| Gender | F | 1 |
| Surname | Jones | 2 |
| First Name | Ben | 2 |
| Title | Mr | 2 |
| Gender | M | 2 |

Which I am hoping to get results which would appear like this:

| Record No | Title | First Name | Second Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mrs | Anne | Smith | F |
| 2 | Mr | Ben | Jones | M |

I am guessing using PIVOT would the be way to achieve this? I have tried putting a statement together for this but I have no idea what I would put for the aggregation as I do not wish to aggregate in this instance.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: If you're guaranteed to only have a single value per row/column combination, several aggregate functions such as `MAX` will return their single input as the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `MAX` function. You MUST use some kind of aggregate function on `PIVOT`

The syntax will be something like `PIVOT(MAX(Detail) FOR Property IN (Surname, FirstName....)`